# Why Gradle Task "Run" passes command line arguments isn't comprehensible

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I've tested a few recommendations from the internet to check but nothing seems to explain why the arguments are passed to the main method of the main class.

My checks included:

- Run/Debug Configuration
- Args assignment in run-Task
- Args assignment in execution-Task (type: JavaExec)
- IntelliJ settings

The arguments which are passed to main are:

- "mainClassName" -> Assigned in application-task
- JVM-Arguments ["-Xms256m", "-Xmx1g", "-Dfile.encoding...", "-Duser.country=...", "-Duser.language...", +3 more] -> ["-Xms256m", "-Xmx1g"]: These values are also assigned in application-task. So if I change these values, the arguments in main are also changed.

Has somebody any idea where these arguments could come from if I start the run task? Thx in advance.